# Find most common occurrence of property with specific string in a 2 level array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a MOBA hero counters app and I need to find the common counters of a hero for a team.

What I have is this:

```
[
    {
        "counters": [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "k"}]
    },
    {
        "counters": [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "y"}]
    },
    {
        "counters": [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "c"}]
    },
    {
        "counters": [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "g"}, {"name": "f"}]
    },
    {
        "counters": [{"name": "x"}, {"name": "z"}, {"name": "y"}]
    }
]
```

What I need to do is find out the most common counters with the same name property and display them at the top of the list. So if `name: "a"` repeats 3 times, I want to be able to sort by it and display it at the top of the list.

Problem is, I do not know how to achieve this. Can anyone please help me out?

This is what I have so far:

```js
const generateCounters = (hero) => {
  const positiveCounters = hero.counters.filter((counter) => parseFloat(counter.disadvantage.replace('%', '')) >= 0.00);
    
  return positiveCounters.map(counter => {
    return (
      <div className="relative-el">
        <img className="hero-image" src={`/assets/images/${replaceHeroName(counter.name)}.png`} alt="" width={86} />
        <p className="absolute-statistic">{counter.disadvantage}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
    
const renderCounters = () => {
  return activeHeroes.map(hero => {
    return (
      <div className="hero-counters-container">
        <div className="relative-el header-hero">
          <img className="hero-image" src={`/assets/images/${hero.heroName.replaceAll(' ', "-").replace("'", "").toLowerCase()}.png`} alt="" width={86} />
        </div>
        <div className="counters-list">
          {generateCounters(hero)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

EDIT: `activeHeroes` is the variable holding the json structure above.

Comment: The above is not a valid structure. Have you perhaps left in some more curly braces than needed?

Comment: @KamenMinkov Edited. Sorry, I didn't double check when I wrote this.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you want to sort, and on what basis.  Do you want to sort the items in `activeHeroes` or to sort their `counter` properties individually?  And do you want to sort them according to the number of `counter` items with a given `name` in that particular hero, or according to the total number of `counter` items with a given `name` among *all* the heros?  Is this to run before `positiveHeros .sort (...)`?  Sample output to match a small input would probably go a long way to answering these questions.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Basically I want to display all the counters for each hero (which is the 5 objects in the first array) but I want them to show in order of most frequent occurrence. So if 4/5 heroes in a team have the same counter I want those 4 counters to show first, then all counters that counter 3 heroes and so on..

Comment: As far as I can tell, your input data is already sorted in that order.  There are more `a`s than anything else, and `a` come first in every list.  Perhaps a different input is in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want.  I had to change your input data as it seems that your input was the same as the output you wanted, so the change wasn't visible.  It should run before the `activeHeros .map` call in `render`, I believe.

```js
const countBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a [k] = (a [k] || 0) + 1), a), {})

const sortCounters = (
  heros, 
  index = countBy (c => c .name) (heros .flatMap (h => h .counters))
) => heros .map (
  hero => ({
    ... hero, 
    counters: [...hero .counters] .sort (
      (a, b) => index [b .name] - index [a .name]
    ) 
  })
)

const heros = [
  {counters: [{name: "a"}, {name: "k"}, {name: "q"}]},
  {counters: [{name: "k"}, {name: "q"}, {name: "y"}]},
  {counters: [{name: "k"}, {name: "q"}, {name: "w"}]},
  {counters: [{name: "b"}, {name: "p"}, {name: "q"}]},
  {counters: [{name: "d"}, {name: "e"}, {name: "f"}]}
]

console .log (sortCounters (heros)) /* => [
  {counters: [{name: "q"}, {name: "k"}, {name: "a"}]}, 
  {counters: [{name: "q"}, {name: "k"}, {name: "y"}]}, 
  {counters: [{name: "q"}, {name: "k"}, {name: "w"}]}, 
  {counters: [{name: "q"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "p"}]}, 
  {counters: [{name: "d"}, {name: "e"}, {name: "f"}]}
]  */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we have a function `sortCounters` that takes an array of heros (?), objects with `counters` array properties containing items that have a `name` property.  We use a `countBy` helper to create an index, something like:

```js
{a: 1, k: 3, q: 4, y: 1, w: 1, b: 1, p: 1, d: 1, e: 1, f: 1}
```

Then we copy each hero, sorting its counters according to the counts in that list.  If they are the same, we don't care, but most (all?) modern JS engines implement a stable sort, meaning they won't get reordered if they are all the same.  We could easily add a secondary sort by name or something else if desired.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up doing something similar, but this is what I wanted pretty much.